# Connection to SQL database failed.

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

With my windows service application I am trying to connect 2 databases called db1 and db2.  Both db db1 and db2 are present in one SQL server.

I am able to connect db1 using service and fetch required details but I am getting below error while connecting db2

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

I guess this issue may be because of db/server name is incorrect in connection string  while connecting to db2. 
This is working fine in development environment but not in live.
Is there any way so that we can find out what db/server name it is trying to connect without debugging.
**Is there anything like error logs for sql which will capture during connection?**

Comment: Whether your login has access to `db2`

Comment: Considering that you're still testing and you are looking for logs, **why not make your own?** Just try catch that connection and output the exception and relevant data (ex. connection strings, user name etc.) into a text file

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre I completed development, in that case I have to modify code That is good Idea of logging connection I never thought of. 

I checked in event viewer but it don't  have server/db name

Comment: @Prdp ,Yes it has access to db2.

Comment: You need the sqlserver to be configured to accept multiple connections from the same user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify your firewall settings. The default port is TCP 1433. To rule out the firewall you may disable/enable it, and try to connect.

Use SQL Server Configuration Manager and verify the services are running.

Comment: yes sqlserver service is running, otherwise it wont have connected db1 also.

Answer (score 0):

First try to test  connection  the mentioned database from your application. I think  the issue is because of your login credentials. Please verify first.

Comment: I can login to SQL server via SSMS with the same credentials mentioned in config for that particular user.

Comment: https://youtu.be/OEcd5oRRPmM. Follow this video and connect from your application.